# How to get file root value from html form or php

Tags: php, html, yii2

I want to save `directory root` value of file to `database`.

ex: 
I have file with directory `c:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\app\views\index.php`  , but i just want get `myproject\app\views\index.php`.
I want to get value from the input type file, is it possible ?

This is how proccess I want to build, but the value not like I want.

[image: not like what i want]

i want when user click choose file in `<input type='file' />`, i want default directory open in "myproject" . it's not about uploading file, i just want make validation from directory root value. in some case i have 2 file with same name "index.php", but one of file located in `myproject\view\dir1\index.php` and another one in `myproject\view\dir2\index.php`.
so that sets it apart is the root directory.

thanks for help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the follwing:

`\Yii::$app->basePath` will give like `D:\xampp\htdocs\advanced\backend`

`\Yii::$app->request->BaseUrl` will give like `localhost\advanced\backend\web\`

You may store the image using `\Yii::$app->basePath` and show it using `\Yii::$app->request->BaseUrl`

Hope it helps

Comment: @chinmay i want user choose file, and show directory root file from "myproject"  not c:\xampp\htdocs\myproject , is it possible ?
and when click choose file in "<input type='file' />, i want default directory open in "myproject" . it's not about uploading file, i just want make validation from directory root value. in some case i have 2 file with same name "index.php", but one of file located in myproject\view\dir1\index.php and another one in myproject\view\dir2\index.php .

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand. Could you please update your question accordingly

Comment: @chinmay there another problem my picture, can you look value in object name column ? it's actually c:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\views\dir1\index.php, not C:\fakepath\index.php

Comment: So the question is? Which path do you want there?

Comment: how to get value of <input type="text"> , and custom the value ?

Comment: Sorry dude not getting you. Can you post it as the new question. And if you find my answer helpful you can mark it as accepted :)

Comment: yes i want custom value of <input type="file">. i'll using that value for validation form. hehe

Comment: i have new question about clean url in yii2 , may you can help me :)

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29885970/how-to-remove-url-web-index-php-yii-2-and-set-route-with-parameter-with-clean

Comment: I would be more than happy to help you. You can check the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Please google the followings. Also search in stackoverflow

```
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] dirname(__FILE__);
```

Comment: i want get dir root from <input type="file" /> or some kind , so user can choose file.