# how to remove url (/web/index.php) yii 2 and set route with parameter with clean url?

Tags: php, .htaccess, yii2, clean-urls, yii-url-manager

first question:
 i already remove `index.php`, but i want remove `/web` also. this is my `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine on
# If a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

and this is `config/web.php`

```
'urlManager' => [
            'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
            // Disable index.php
            'showScriptName' => false,
            // Disable r= routes
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'rules' => array(
                    '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
                    '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
                    '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
            ),
        ],
```

it's working fine, but it's still using `/web` .
is it possible remove `/web` ?

second question:

i can't set route with parameter with that clean url, my route `Url::toRoute(['transaction/getrequestdetail/', 'id' => 1 ]);`

how the route should be ? and how with 2 parameter route ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**For advanced application follow these steps:**

1) Add the following `htaccess` to `frontend/web`

```
RewriteEngine on

# If a directory or a file exists, use the request directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Otherwise forward the request to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

2) Add the following `htaccess` to `root folder` where application is installed

```
# prevent directory listings
Options -Indexes
IndexIgnore */*

# follow symbolic links
Options FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^admin(/.+)?$ backend/web/$1 [L,PT]
RewriteRule ^(.+)?$ frontend/web/$1
```

3) Edit your `frontend/config/main.php` file with the following at the top

```
use \yii\web\Request;
$baseUrl = str_replace('/frontend/web', '', (new Request)->getBaseUrl());
```

4) Add the `request component` to the components array in the same file i.e `frontend/config/main.php`

```
'components' => [
        'request' => [
            'baseUrl' => $baseUrl,
        ],
],
```

That's it.Now you can access the frontend without web/index.php

For you second question you need to write the rule for it in your URL manager component.

Something like this:

```
'urlManager' => [
            'baseUrl' => $baseUrl,
            'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
            // Disable index.php
            'showScriptName' => false,
            // Disable r= routes
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'rules' => array(
                    'transaction/getrequestdetail/<id>' => 'transaction/getrequestdetail',
           ),
],
```

Comment: thank's for answer bro, but i still have trouble with second question.
the url result still: http://localhost/transmansys/objecttransaction/index&id=100049 with that rules.
i need url result be: http://localhost/transmansys/objecttransaction/index/100049.

and how about url with 2 or more parameter ?

Comment: solved bro, i just need add " / " after <id> in your rules lol.
thank you very much dude :D

Comment: @Chinmay what if I have a basic template. how I would write the number 2? I hope you might answer. thanks

Comment: @BlackSkull I have not used basic template as yet. But is shouldn't be that hard. This link might help you: http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/47615-yii-20-basci-app-i-miss-the-htaccess-file/page__view__findpost__p__280436

Comment: The perfect solution. Thanks @Chinmay

Comment: It s working perfectly, even for basic template.Thanks

Comment: This may break some URLs, see explanation and alternative in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49955912/5812455)

Answer (score 4):

If it still isn't working after going through the answers above, then you can edit your 'apache2.conf' file in your favorite editor to change

**AllowOveride None** to **AllowOveride All**

On Ubuntu, the file is located at */etc/apache2/apache2.conf*

The final edit should look like

```
<Directory /var/www/>
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride All
  Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Finally, restart the Apache server

Comment: This is the solution

Answer (score 1):

You can add the information in file configuration to remove /web:

```
$baseUrl = str_replace('/web', '', (new Request)->getBaseUrl());

return [
    ...
    'components' => [
            'request' => [
                'baseUrl' => $baseUrl,
     ],
      ...
    ]
]
```

Comment: You can change htaccess: Options -Indexes

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
  RewriteEngine on

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^web
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ web/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

# Deny accessing below extensions
<Files ~ "(.json|.lock|.git)">
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
</Files>

# Deny accessing dot files
RewriteRule (^\.|/\.) - [F]

Comment: still "object not found", can you write .htaccess in your answer ? (edit your answer). i maybe I mistyped.

Comment: You can move $baseUrl in config to ... 'urlManager' => [
            'baseUrl' => $baseUrl,
            'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager', ...]

Answer (score 0):

Using `str_replace('/frontend/web', '', (new Request)->getBaseUrl())` for detecting base URL is a bad idea and using `str_replace('/web', '', (new Request)->getBaseUrl())` is a terrible idea. `str_replace()` removes all occurences of requested string, so `str_replace('/frontend/web', '', (new Request)->getBaseUrl())` for URL `/frontend/web/tools/frontend/webalizer` will give you `/toolsalizer`. Definitely not a thing that you want.

If you want to remove this string only from the begging of URL:

```
$baseUrl = (new Request())->getBaseUrl();
if ($baseUrl === '/frontend/web') {
    $baseUrl = '';
} elseif (strncmp($baseUrl, '/frontend/web/', 14) === 0) {
    $baseUrl = substr($baseUrl, 13);
}
```

But the best solution would be avoiding the whole problem in the first place, for example by [using symlinks to mimic required directory structure for single webroot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49826324/5812455).